Does membership of a consensus panel count as a publication when the article involved your participation
Does membership of a consensus panel count as a publication when the article involved your participation but not one of the main 5 listed authors who contributed more to the publication

"Count" for who, for what purpose? To clarify, this is a case where the authors are listed something like "A Adams, B Bonham, C Chen, D Donald, E Erickson, and the Underwater Basketweaving Consensus Committee", right?

Participation on a consensus panel "counts" as participation on a consensus panel.  Participation means that you were recognized as having adequate expertise to participate, and thus this belongs in your CV.  The most obvious issue for me is where it goes in your CV, and that would be most dependent on the nature of the panel and whether this is intramural or extramural work.
However, it doesn't count as a "publication", unless the panel produced some sort of report.  If a report was generated, then you need to figure out if it needs to go in a peer-reviewed list or a non-peer reviewed list of publications.

And even if one were on the panel they may not be an author on a report.
